# XSLT compare two elements

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have this xml

```
<magazine>
  ...
  <startPage>14</startPage>
  <endPage>14</endPage>
  ...
</magazine>

<magazine>
  ...
  <startPage>27</startPage>
  <endPage>30</endPage>
  ...
</magazine>
```

I want to compare the value of the `startPage` and `endPage` to see if those two pages are equal

i.e.

> if `startPage` = `endPage` -> do something;
>
> if not -> do something else

How should I approach this in XSLT?

Comment: Could I ask, where did you look for information before asking here? Asking a question on StackOverflow shouldn't be a substitute for looking in manuals, specifications, tutorial sites, or textbooks. And xsl:choose is surely a very basic feature covered by all such sources. I'm therefore going to downvote the question as showing insufficient research. But please don't let that put you off coming back with further questions in future.

Comment: I did googled before asking here, but my 'real' problem is not actually this one, I am just asking it in a different way and in a much easier way. I spent quite some time to figure out what to do exactly after the answer below came out. I just didn't think that the question i had was this easy to solve. Anyway thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `xsl:choose` here...

```
<xsl:template match="magazine">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="startPage = endPage">
        <xsl:text>EQUAL</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>NOT EQUAL</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or you could put the check in the template match, and have separate templates for each of your different logic

```
<xsl:template match="magazine[startPage = endPage]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>EQUAL</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="magazine">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:text>NOT EQUAL</xsl:text>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

See the latter option in action at http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiKj